# Why don't the cricket spectators come to the ground after completion of innings any more?

Tags: cricket

After 1983 World cup, players ran away from the pitch.

In cricket, crowds used to come to the ground after the completion of an innings, but now they don't. Why has this phenomenon stopped?

Comment: Imagine 30k+ people on the ground, destroying the pitch which took years to build and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

It's no different in cricket than in any other sport: it's dangerous for the players, the officials and everyone else involved in the game.

Comment: This seems right, but this would be a better answer with information about when this changed and if some specific event predicated the change.

Answer (score 2):

Instances of the spectators rushing down the ground have decreased because of the increased security around the field, the spectators still want to do that but nowadays there is a obstruction net to stop them from coming.
The main reason behind doing this is player security, I mean it does not take much time for the crowd to turn in to a riot I would like to give an example here, India had lost a match (I don't remember the opposition) at home and the spectators got so angry that they started throwing bottles and stones at the players, just imagine what would have happened if there were no measures to stop the spectators from entering the field.

Another reason would be that if so many people came rambling on the ground, the pitch and the whole ground would be completely destroyed and it takes a lot of time to prepare a ground and then maintain it.